# update value another file

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm building a react-native app and i need to change theme color for every user type. I am pulling this color code from server and keep in asyncstorage.

i tried add func for changing primary color variable but the code passing them without wait give me promise not value

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

let primaryColor = "orange"

const func = async () => {
    let some;
    let thing = await AsyncStorage.getItem("profile")
    thing = JSON.parse(thing)
    console.warn("thing", thing.background)
    if (thing.background != undefined) {
        some = thing.background
    } else if (thing == undefined) {
        some = "red"
    }
    return some
}

primaryColor = func()
```

original:

```
let primaryColor = "orange";

let color = {
    primaryColor: primaryColor,
    darkPrimaryColor: "#C31C0D",
    lightPrimaryColor: "#FF8A65",
    accentColor: "#4A90A4"

export let BaseColor = {
    ...color,
    ... {
        textPrimaryColor: "#212121",
        textSecondaryColor: "#E0E0E1",
        grayColor: "#9B9B9B",
        darkBlueColor: "#24253D",
        dividerColor: "#BDBDBD",
        whiteColor: "#FFFFFF",
        fieldColor: "#F5F5F5",
        yellowColor: "#FDC60A",
        navyBlue: "#3C5A99"
    }
};
```

Comment: Well of course it will give you promise if you don't await it. I don't get what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is asynchronous. Get the value by acting asynchronously.

### Example

```js
async componentDidMount(){

  primaryColor = await func() 
}
```

Comment: componentdidmount will not work because there isn't any component just below the original. variable and export

Answer (score 0):

fetch the resolved result from your function before setting it to your 'primaryColor'

```
func()

.then(color => primaryColor = color);
```

And catch any error there might be.

```
.catch((e) => console.error(e))
```

or if you are using it within a async function you can simply

```
try {
    primaryColor = await func();
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
}
```